# How to realize a gradient like this with css

Tags: css

Is it possible to realize this pattern with css without using a background image?

[image]

Comment: Quick google search gave me this result http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and http://ie.microsoft.com/TESTDRIVE/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html

Comment: It can be done using CSS3. Check here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.button_example{
border:1px solid #cacaca; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; -moz-border-radius: 50px;border-radius: 50px;font-size:57px;font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block;text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);font-weight:bold; color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #E6E6E6; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#E6E6E6), to(#CCCCCC));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6, #CCCCCC);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6, #CCCCCC);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6, #CCCCCC);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6, #CCCCCC);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E6E6E6, #CCCCCC);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#E6E6E6, endColorstr=#CCCCCC);
}
```